# Unable to locate metadata resource with BreezeSharp on Xamarin client

Tags: c#, xamarin, breeze, breeze-sharp

I have setup an ASP.Net WebApi site that uses Breeze to serve data. I also have an angular webclient using BreezeJs which talks successfully to the webapi and gets data.

Currently, I am trying to connect a Xamarin client to the WebApi using Breeze# but I am unable to get it working and get a 'Unable to locate metadata resource' error.

I have tried using the Breeze# [ToDo.Xamarin example](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.sharp.samples) but hit the same issue with the error: 
`"Unable to locate metadata resource for: http://localhost:60851/breeze/todos/"`
, even though the url `http://localhost:60851/breeze/todos/Metadata` works successfully in the browser.

I have fiddler running and there is no attempt to contact the server from the app.

What am I missing to get the client to talk to the server?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "even though the URL works successfully in the browser", do you mean the browser on your mobile device or on your PC? If you haven't tried the URL in your phones browser, give it a shot. It's possible your environment isn't configured correctly to support the use of 'localhost' from you're mobile devices point of view.